# Cannot use RotateRight function to move points in plot forward

Tags: plotting, rotation

I have a plot of activity which is matched to degrees of crank angle on the x axis.    I want to move the plot forward by 180 degrees in to work to have the peak occuring at the beginning of the cycle, and tried the `RotateRight` function, but cannot get it to work because of the integer.  Is there a way around this or another way?

```
circLEangle = {};
spoints = 100;
Do[
    u = Interpolation[angleSplitNorm[[i]]];
    ang = Table[
   u[1 + (Length[angleSplitNorm[[i]]] - 1)*(m/(spoints - 1))], {m, 
    0, (spoints - 1)}];
    u = Interpolation[circLEsplitnorm[[i]]];
    velLE = 
  Table[u[1 + (Length[circLEsplitnorm[[i]]] - 
        1)*(m/(spoints - 1))], {m, 0, (spoints - 1)}];
    AppendTo[circLEangle, Transpose[{ang, velLE}]],
 {i, 4, 42}]

ListPlot[Table[circLEangle[[i]], {i, Length[circLEangle]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 360}, All}, Joined -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Crank Angle [Deg]", "Crank Angular Velocity [deg/s]"},
  LabelStyle -> {"Arial", 14}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: plot output]

Comment: Some thoughts ... You have to split your points into two parts according to horizontal (first) coordinate: before and after 180, then shift them to +/- 180 correspondingly. This can be done like this (for 1 dataset of points): `right=Cases[points, {x_/;x>=180, y_}:>{x-180,y}]; left=Cases[data,{x_/;x<180, y_}:>{x+180,y}]; Plot[Join[right, left]]`.

Comment: Even simplier: `newtable=Table[circLEangle[[i]], {i, Length[circLEangle]}]/.{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}:>{If[x>=180,x-180,x+180],y}`, then `ListPlot[newtable, ...]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help :)